# Wordpress local installation with WAMP or XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp, wamp

I have a new laptop and im trying to set up a local Apache/PHP/MySQL to work on my Wordpress projects (I only need it for WP, nothing else). I tried with both WAMP and XAMPP, and it's something I did many times on my old computer (create a database, edit wp-config and then install wp by going to localhost/sitename). But this time, I get to the WP install screen step (where I have to input the site name, my email, and the admin username / password) and after that the installation goes to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/sitename/wp-admin/install.php?step=2
```

where I get a blank page, with just a WP logo at the top. Wordpress is 3.8.1 and i got the latest WAMP and XAMPP from their websites. In PHPMyAdmin I can see that the instalation created 11 tables in the site database.

I tried uninstalling XAMPP, reinstalling it, and then I tried with WAMP, always the same result. I have win8.1 installed, not sure if that matters.

UPDATE: I have the WP installed and I can access it with localhost/sitename, but I cant log in as admin (username and password are not recognized) and it says "ERROR: There is no user registered with that email address" when I try to retrieve my password.

Comment: Normally, the address would be something like `http://localhost/wp-admin/install.php` not `http://localhost/sitename/wp-admin/install.php`. If you are installing to a directory, follow [these instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it after finding this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/installation-hangs-on-step-2-after-creating-basic-dbs-without-admin-user?replies=16

so i just edited the php.ini file as suggested in that post (increased the max_execution_time) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the pre-requisites for installing Wordpress ?

To run WordPress your host just needs a couple of things:

- PHP version 5.2.4 or greater
- MySQL version 5.0 or greater

The requirements have changed as of WordPress 3.2. The minimum requirements for WordPress 3.1 are PHP 4.3 and MySQL 4.1.2.

Apache or Nginx are recommended as the most robust and featureful server for running WordPress, but any server that supports PHP and MySQL will do.

(Source is [HERE](http://wordpress.org/about/requirements/))

Comment: Im guessing the latest WAMP and XAMPP both have the minimum requisites since my old XAMPP on my old computer runs the latest WP with no problem.Also, the download link for xampp says PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: @user1875215 i know what you mean, but i think it's better to check the setting of your server.

Comment: @user1875215 Did you try to installing WP without setup process ?

Comment: I edited the wp-config file manually (database name, username, password), and then navigated to the localhost/sitename. Filled out the form (site name etc.) and clicked "Install"...then the instalation creaates the tables in the db (11 of them) but the browser goes to a blank page.

Comment: @user1875215 you can try something else, install wp in other webhosting and export DB of there , then import DB into your local.

Comment: I could but that wouldnt solve my problem, because I need to get it working on this machine, since there are a few sites im working on, so I would like to be able to do the whole WP instalation process localy, like I can on my old PC.

Comment: @user1875215 can debug mode gets activated in setup process ? check it maybe helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the wp-config.php file from the root and remove the database tables. Now try with the wordpress installation. It may help you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, several times, but it didnt work. Apparently, the problem was max_execution_time in php.ini, I increased it and now it works.